# How to display my rendered scene on a new monitor while i am still working on solid mode in my laptop?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, interface, customization

I have connected my monitor to my laptop and I want the rendered view to be seen in monitor and I want to work on solid mode at the same time.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

Click on `View` in the bottom menu of your 3D window and choose `Duplicate Area into New Window`. Simply drag the new window onto the other screen and switch to rendered view.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to drag a triangle in views corner while having a <kbd>shift</kbd> pressed this will detach the window and let you move it to other screen.

[image: Just shift+click]